# problems with xml output from C# webservice and/or xpath query

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

The webservice I've build returns XML by default, I added my own XML nodes which I need to query in a different application (Nintex). I do that with Xpath. But I can't seem to get the result I want...

```
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public struct aduser
    {
        public String result;
        public String username;
        public String email;
        public String password;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public aduser CreateADUser(string domain, ...

    ...
    ...
    ...

    user.result = "Succes";
    user.username = loginName;
    user.email = emailAddress;
    user.password = password;

    return user;
}
```

The result I get is

```
<xml>
    <result xmlns="http://dev01/">Succes</result>
    <username xmlns="http://dev01/">test0101</username>
    <email xmlns="http://dev01/">test0101@dev01.local</email>
    <password xmlns="http://dev01/">somepassword</password>
</xml>
```

so when I try to extract for example the result value by doing /xml/result It does not work, I can't read out the value or do debugging because Nintex won't let me... I've tried a lot of different xpath queries but none give the result I want, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is probably a rookieproblem but I'm really stuck here :-(

Comment: Can you show a short snippet of code to let us know what you are trying?

Comment: well, the above code is all the code I use for the output, rest (which I didnt copied) is just code to fill those variabeles...

what I use in Nintex is "/xml/result/text()", this query I created in Liquid XML studio by trial and error on the initial XML output I get from the webservice...

I do think it has to do with the lack of a namespace...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Nintex products but your problem is you need to inform whatever XPath processor you are using about the "http://dev01/" namespace.

Typically this is done by using a namespace manager object and associating an XPath processor or passing as a parameter when executing the XPath.

The namespace manager holds a list of namespaces and the aliases being used for them.  So in this example you could associate the aliaes 'a' with "http://dev01/".  Your XPath would become:-  `/xml/a:result`.

By way of an idea here is what it would look like in C# (how port this to your Nintex tool I don't know).

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://dev01/");
XmlNode resultNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/xml/a:result", nsmgr);
```

Comment: thnx for the answer, I'm gonna try to build this in my app!

Answer (score 0):

The C# code cannot be used to parse XML output in Nintex since Nintex "Call Web Service" action is configured in the SharePoint GUI (as well as all other actions) so I don't really think that the previous answer is somehow relevant.

To find out how your web service output looks like for Nintex you can use the method described in the following blog post:
http://vtonms.blogspot.com/2009/12/nintex-workflow-web-service-xml-result.html

When you get an impression what you actually get in your workflow variable from the web service, you can easily use "Query XML" integration action to get the details you need from the XML. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: The link above does not work, can you perhaps describe the solution?

Comment: It was five years ago, a bit late to remember